# Windows XP difficulty connecting to Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-xp

I'm having difficulty connecting Windows XP machines to Windows Server 2008 via their network name (\\server) At times, I can only get to the server through \\ip address. I think I've resolved this issue by turning netBIOS on. However, at times the server comes up without authenticating. Other times it doesn't remember authentication. (even when the check box is clicked)

This is an issues because we're running some software that calls upon the server by name and fails to connect when it cannot find it in this manner.

This seems like a simple issue, but I'm not 100% sure what's going wrong here. Is this a netBIOS issue? An xp/server2008r2 compatibility issue? Or is it an issue with my network?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the XP workstation might not be getting the correct DNS record for the Windows 2008 server. You should run the command

```
nslookup <win2008server>
```

from a command prompt on the XP workstation during one of the windows when \\servername does not work.

If you get a message about not being able to find servername, or nslookup shows you a different IP from the one that you know it has, then your DNS server or workstation DNS settings will be a good place to start checking.

In all likelihood your server already has a static IP, but if not, that could contribute to this problem, and you should consider changing it to be statically configured.

Additionally, you may wish to try the FQDN (Fully Qualified Domain Name) of the server (\\servername.foo.com), depending on your AD environment.

Comment: I think the question above is concerning connecting to Windows Server 2008 from Windows XP. Authenticated or not, even in a simple workgroup can ask for authentication, not just in AD.

Comment: If we can rule out connection problems, that will put jeremyhappens in a place where he can examine the authentication situation. In a workgroup environment he should be able to set the username/password pair on the XP machine to match a username/password pair on the Windows 2008 server, which should prevent being prompted for credentials.